# Excel VBA: Date Comparison

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-2010

So I'm currently trying to make a code to compare the current date to two other dates in order to determine the validity of information. For example, if the date is between the first quarter of the year and the second quarter, the information on the document is as of the first quarter date (March 31). Below is what I currently have and for some reason even though the current date is in July, the code keeps saying the information is valid as of March 31. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
crntDate = Date
q1End = CDate("Mar 31" & " " & Year(Date))
q2End = CDate("Jun 30" & " " & Year(Date))
q3End = CDate("Sep 30" & " " & Year(Date))
q4End = CDate("Dec 31" & " " & Year(Date))

If q1End <= crntDate <= q2End Then
    quart = "Q1" & " " & Year(Date)
ElseIf q2End <= crntDate <= q3End Then
    quart = "Q2" & " " & Year(Date)
ElseIf q3End <= crntDate <= q4End Then
    quart = "Q3" & " " & Year(Date)
Else
    quart = "Q4" & " " & Year(Date)
End If

shName = "Quarterly Reporting for" & " " & firstName & " " & lastName & " " & "(" & quart & ")"
With wdApp.ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs2 "https://path/" & shName & ".docx"
    .Close
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to format dates as quarters, you don't need all of the end dates and comparisons, you can just use integer division `\` in VBA.

```
Sub test()

  Dim quart As String
  quart = GetDateAsQuarterYear(VBA.Date)

  shName = "Quarterly Reporting for" & " " & firstName & " " & lastName & " " & "(" & quart & ")"
  With wdApp.ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs2 "https://path/" & shName & ".docx"
    .Close
  End With
End Sub

Function GetDateAsQuarterYear(crntDate As Date) As String

  Dim quarterEnd As Date
  quarterEnd = DateSerial(Year(crntDate), 1 + 3 * (1 + (Month(crntDate) - 1) \ 3), 0)

  GetDateAsQuarterYear = "Q" & 1 + (Month(crntDate) - 1) \ 3 & " (" & Format$(quarterEnd, "mmmm d, yyyy") & ")"

End Function
```

Comment: What about if I was looking for the actual quarter dates to appear aswell with the function? (i.e. March 31, YEAR for Q1, June 30, YEAR for Q2, etc)

Comment: I've updated the code to fix a bug in non-quarter-end months, and to add the quarter-end date in a format like `Q3 (September 30, 2017)`

Answer (score 2):

`q1End <= crntDate <= q2End` does not work in Excel it needs to be:

```
q1End <= crntDate  and crntDate <= q2End
```

So

```
crntDate = Date
q1End = CDate("Mar 31" & " " & Year(Date))
q2End = CDate("Jun 30" & " " & Year(Date))
q3End = CDate("Sep 30" & " " & Year(Date))
q4End = CDate("Dec 31" & " " & Year(Date))

If q1End <= crntDate  and crntDate <= q2End Then
    quart = "Q2" & " " & Year(Date)
ElseIf q2End <= crntDate  and crntDate <= q3End Then
    quart = "Q3" & " " & Year(Date)
ElseIf q3End <= crntDate  and crntDate <= q4End Then
    quart = "Q4" & " " & Year(Date)
Else
    quart = "Q1" & " " & Year(Date)
End If

shName = "Quarterly Reporting for" & " " & firstName & " " & lastName & " " & "(" & quart & ")"
With wdApp.ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs2 "https://path/" & shName & ".docx"
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: damn, was just about to post :)

Comment: Still thinking like I'm programming in Python - thanks a bunch @ScottCraner :)

Comment: IIUC,, CDate is going to be subject to the regional/language settings of the user, so if you're declaring dates in VBA, you'll be better off using `DateSerial(year,month,day)` or the native syntax `#mm/dd/yyyy#`.

Comment: It would also be unfortunate if the code was run at midnight on New Year's Eve, as the repeated calls to `Year(Date)` might end up with different years.

Comment: You missed the elegant solution of just using integer division for quarters ;-p

Comment: @ThunderFrame I just wanted to show the error and how to overcome it.  As to making it better, meh... I will leave that to you guys who frequent CodeReview. :)